# What is voltage input and voltage output?

Tags: wave

I'm so confused about what these are. On a half wave rectification circuit this is labelled at the end with a wave coming out of it:
[image]

I understand that this wave is just showing the half wave rectification however I don't understand why this is associated with voltage output?

Also, with a **full wave rectification** circuit, there is a part of the circuit that is labelled 'load':

[image]

What does this mean? And why is there a label saying DC?

Comment: Load is any device connected to the circuit. It is shown by a resistor because each device has it resistance and the current has to flow through it. The result you are getting from the circuit is a DC current hence labelled as DC.

Answer (score 1):

Your schemes are solutions to go from AC (alternated current) to DC (direct current). The difference with those currents is that AC will alternate from polarity and DC not. DC will stay at the same side. Rectifiers are used because the electrical power that you find at walls are AC and most devices (load) uses DC.

For example on your first scheme your input is AC and output is DC. On the second scheme the output will also be DC but you will have less loss. As you can see on the first scheme you only have the positive part of your input (which is a sinus).

The output that you will get on the second image will be:
[image: output full wave rectification[1]]

This is called output because it is the end result of your scheme. You started with a sinus and then at the end you have a result that is called output.

On your output you will attach a device that is called load. For example a TV or a computer. A load can be everything that consumes electrical power.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously haven't taken the trouble of googling about the theory behind these rectifier circuits.

Now as an attempt to answer your question  let us see what we can get from Google:

1. This is a very good resource to understand the theory behind the Half Wave rectifier circuit as it is very important. [Half wave rectification theory](http://www.circuitstoday.com/half-wave-rectifiers#theory)
2. This is a very good resource to understand about the circuits regarding Half Wave rectification. [Half wave rectification circuits](http://www.circuitstoday.com/half-wave-rectifiers)
3. This a good resource for understand Full Wave rectification.[Full wave rectification](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html)

Now what is Load : *An electrical load is an electrical component or portion of a circuit that consumes electric power. This is opposed to a power source, such as a battery or generator, which produces power. In electric power circuits examples of loads are appliances and lights. The term may also refer to the power consumed by a circuit.* If you want to go deeper check the wikipedia link [Wikipedia: Load](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwingL7m4P7MAhVGwI8KHUjNDKIQFgg6MAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FElectrical_load&usg=AFQjCNGuFSi91c1PFuCLERlrc_telhHQYw&sig2=HtUahiscIHVO_wyy-KUATA)

Do the reading, If you then don't understand you can post a comment and I will try to explain.